# websocket connect to Nitrous.io but break automatically after 1 minute

Tags: websocket, nitrousio, nitrous

I used websocket c++ code connects to Nitrous.io box(nodes.js server) on port 8888.

Everything works well, only if there is no transfer between server and client after a certain time(1 minute) the connection is closed.

The same client works well if server hosts on my other server rather than Nitrous.io box

Just wonder if there is any limitation Nitrous.io websocket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently within `nginx.conf` of the Nitrous boxes, the value `keepalive_timeout 5` is most likely causing the timeout of your WebSockets connection.

Unfortunately without root access this cannot be adjusted, but we (the Nitrous team) will look into increasing this value in an update. I'll update this thread once we have an update.